# Show specific elements in a comma- separated stringbuffer

Tags: java

I am working with SNMP4J and have it successfully outputting comma separated strings (from SNMP traps).

i.e.

```
StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
msg.append(event.toString());
Vector<? extends VariableBinding> varBinds = event.getPDU().getVariableBindings();
if (varBinds != null && !varBinds.isEmpty()) {
    Iterator<? extends VariableBinding> varIter = varBinds.iterator();
    while (varIter.hasNext()) {
        VariableBinding var = varIter.next();
        msg.append(var.toString()).append(";");
    }
}
System.out.println("Message Received: " + msg.toString());
```

outputs -

```
Message Received: CommandResponderEvent[securityModel=1, securityLevel=1, maxSizeResponsePDU=65535,  etc etc
```

As well as the entire output string I need to display specific elements (in particular

```
peerAddress=192.168.150.210/61263
```

and

```
VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.332.10.14.19.11.0 = Fire]]
```

but only ideally the IP address part (192.168.150.210) and the 'meaning' (Fire)

Do I use split to find specific elements and then substring those or is there a better way?

```
String sixth_word = msg.toString().split(",")[6];
```

Comment: Why are you placing the information in a String, when you can just call the event’s [getPeerAddress](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/CommandResponderEvent.html#getPeerAddress()) method, and the methods of [Variable](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/Variable.html) and its subclasses, to get the data directly?

Comment: Hello VGR, I need both the entire string and individual elements, could you expand on how I would call say just the getPeerAddress (I am a newbie). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need a StringBuffer, since you have [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
String msg = event + " " + String.join(";", event.getPDU().getVariableBindings());
```

Personally, for a diagnostic message, I wouldn’t even bother with String.join:

```
String msg = event + " " + event.getPDU().getVariableBindings();
```

Reading the documentation of the classes you’re using will go a long way toward showing you what is available to you.  If you read [the documentation for CommandResponderEvent](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/CommandResponderEvent.html), you’ll see it has public methods that provide the data you desire:

```
String peerAddress = event.getPeerAddress().toString();
```

Looking at the [documentation of VariableBinding](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/VariableBinding.html), we can see that it has a `getVariable()` method.  Each binding’s Variable is where the “Fire” text comes from:

```
List<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();
for (VariableBinding binding : event.getPDU().getVariableBindings()) {
    variables.add(String.valueOf(binding.getVariable()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks VGR, I had discovered how to get the PeerAddress but the variables are something else, there appears to be some syntax errors in your getVariable method.

Comment: I don’t have SNMP4J installed, so I can’t compile the code at the moment.  Perhaps you could elaborate on the error you’re seeing?

Comment: There appears to be chevrons around <String> and ArrayList<>, not sure if that is correct and cant find symbol ArrayList

Comment: You need to import it, just as you imported Vector.

Comment: ArrayList cannot be converted to String

Comment: As a temporary measure I have added System.out.println(varBinds); to just below the if (varBinds != null && !varBinds.isEmpty()) { and this, though awful, seems to work for the time being.